# In Rails, how do I query my database from JavaScript so that I can fill in a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view that uses the `select` method in Ruby on Rails to return the following code:

```
    <select class="form-control" name="xyz" id="food_id">
    <option value="1">Peach</option>
    <option value="2">Apple</option>
    <option value="3">Orange</option>
    </select>
```

To pass this information over to the JavaScript file, I am basically using a `link_to` method in my view, such as the following:

`<%= link_to "Import text", "#/", :onclick => "fillTextBox()" %>`

In the JS file, how can I basically get the name and description of whatever value is selected in the dropdown? This is as far as I've gotten before I got confused:

```
function fillTextBox(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('food_id');
    var foodID = dropdown[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

I need to do something like:

```
var foodName = Food.find(foodID).name;
var foodDescription = Food.find(foodID).description;
```

Is this possible? The rest of the JS function would basically fill in a textbox using foodName and foodDescription, but I first need to be able to query the database for this information in the first place.

Comment: Make an AJAX call to your app with some kind of GET-request to get the rest of the food data?

Comment: `Food` is not available from javascript. It's a different language, none of your Ruby stuff is there.

Comment: @maxpie yeah I know. Is there a way to make it available? I can't add .erb to the .js file as an extension and have it interpret actual rails code can I?

Comment: The erb only runs before the HTML is sent to the client. You can interpolate into javascript using ruby, but at the end of the day it's still javascript running it.

Comment: @MaxPie gotcha. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [Gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon)?

In your controller:

```
def some_method
  gon.foods = Food.all
end
```

Then in your js

```
gon.foods
```

In your case, you can attach the complete `Food` collection in the controller and then find the `Food` by its `id` in javascript using somethig like this

```
var food = gon.foods.filter(function(food) {
    return food.id === foodID;
})[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I ended up finding a workaround by basically adding a custom attribute in my select method to include the data that I would have otherwise requested from AJAX or using this gem. So now I just basically have `<option value="5" description="abc123">` and just gathering both the value and the description from JS.

Comment: `data-description` I think is a better option

Comment: Gotcha. Agreed. Thanks so much again!